# some Services are not able to be constructed (error while validating the service descriptor)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I am trying to dependency inject my services in .net6 web api project but getting the error some services are not able to be constructed.

my Program.cs is simple looks like this

```
using NSBSL.WebAPI.API;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.RegisterServices();
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false).AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", true);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}



app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

service extension looks like this

```
 public static class ServiceExtensions
    {
        public static void RegisterServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            new LogicFactory().ConfigureServices(services);
        }
    }
```

Logic Factory looks like this

```
 public class LogicFactory : IInjectionFactory
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ISpeedPatternLogic, SpeedPatternLogic>();
            new DatasourceFactory().ConfigureServices(services);
        }
    }
```

then DatasourceFactory looks like this

```
  public class DatasourceFactory : IInjectionFactory
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ISpeedPatternDatasource, SpeedPatternDatasource>();
        }
    }
```

I did this with a startup class in .net5 no problem but I am not sure what I am missing for this to work in .net6

IInjectionFactory is just an interface we have always had in our framework code

```
  public interface IInjectionFactory
    {
        void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services);
    }
```

error stack trace

```
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)
```

I am updating this because I have tried some things. I am not sure what is wrong at all. I have tried adding this in my program.cs to just try to directly inject my interface and class

```
using NSBSL.WebAPI.BusinessLogic.Interfaces.SpeedPattern;
using NSBSL.WebAPI.BusinessLogic.Services.SpeedPattern;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ISpeedPatternLogic, SpeedPatternLogic>();
```

I get the same error I am wondering if it is my interface and class this is how they are constructed

Interface

```
 public interface ISpeedPatternLogic : ILoadable<SpeedPatternModel>
    {
    }
}
```

```
 public interface ILoadable<T> : ILogicBase<T> where T : IModelBase
    {
        Task LoadAsync(CancellationToken token);
    }
```

```
   public class SpeedPatternLogic : ServicesBase<SpeedPatternModel>, ISpeedPatternLogic
    {
        private readonly ISpeedPatternDatasource _speedPatternDatasource;
        public SpeedPatternLogic(INSBSLConfiguration configuration, IMapper mapper, ISpeedPatternDatasource speedPatternDatasource) : base(configuration, mapper)
        {
            _speedPatternDatasource = speedPatternDatasource;
        }

        public async override Task<IEnumerable<SpeedPatternModel>> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SpeedPatternModel>>(await _speedPatternDatasource.GetAllAsync(token));
        }

        public Task LoadAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

my problem was in my framework we have this class

```
    public class NSBSLConfigurationFactory : IInjectionFactory
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.TryAddSingleton<INSBSLConfiguration, NSBSLConfiguration>();
        }
    }
```

then we had this in our apistartup that all of our micro api would inherit from when we would do a new api service

```
   private void RegisterNSBSLConfigurationInterfaces(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            new NSBSLConfigurationFactory().ConfigureServices(services);
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide the error and stack trace?

Comment: put it in the question

Comment: Sorry, it seems that stack trace is cut off. What is the actual error? Is it not able to locate INSBSLConfiguration?

Comment: oh I think I figured it out because in our framework we had apistartup that we inherited from. and it had a register services method that would register that service for the configuration. in .net 6 I am trying to implement it all within the program and I never told it to grab that

Comment: the class was internal I changed it to public but I publish to our nuget folder on a server I uninstall and see a new version of today but when I re-install it doesn't see the new public class